# Ajax + Multiple URLs + Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, load

I am currently working with jQuery Datatables and filling it with Ajax data. I don't have an endpoint that returns all the results, it is based on the page number and amount you want returned. The page has a maximum of 100 results. I of course don't want to long all results at once, however I am not entirely sure how to do this correctly and efficiently since I don't want the loading time long. Any help would be wonderful and appreciated!

```
   $.when(
      $.get("url", function(result) {
            brands.pages = result.totalPages;
            brands.total = result.totalElements;
            brands.data =  [];
            for(var i = 0; i < brands.pages; i++) {
              $.get('url/'+ i +'/size/100', function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        if(key === 'content'){
                            $.each(val, function(num, brand) {
                                brands.data = brands.pages
                            })
                        }
                    });
              });
            }
      }), ).then(function() {
         $('#table').DataTable({
            data: brands.data,
            other options...
         });
      });
```

Comment: you should use datatable's events and over-ride methods so that you can fetch data using datatables instead of build a whole grid from scratch each update...

Comment: So a callback method?